# Searching those emails that have not been received

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have 3 pre build tables:

1) "Schedule" table that has data about emails subject, frequency and sender email ID.
2) "Daily Not Received" email table has all data related to all daily emails that has not been received.
3) "Monday Not Received" email table has all data related to all monday emails that has not been received. (monday emails means those emails that should be received on mondays)

I am trying to search a subject of an email in a schedule table to find its frequency (if the mail is received daily or on Monday). If frequency is daily category, I am searching that subject in daily not received email table and fetching out those emails as an output.
If frequency is monday category, I am searching that subject in monday not received email table and fetching out those emails as an output.

The code is not showing any output. Please guide me.

```
<?php
$input= $_POST["requiredsubject"]; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM schedule WHERE subject = $requiredsubject");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$frequency = $row['day'];


if ($frequency = "daily"){
$resultdaily = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM dailyNR WHERE subject = $requiredsubject");
while ($yahoo = mysql_fetch_array($resultdaily)){
echo $yahoo;
echo($string."\r");
}
}

elseif ($frequency = "monday"){
$resultmonday = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM mondayNR WHERE subject = $requiredsubject");
while ($yahoo = mysql_fetch_array($resultmonday)){
echo $yahoo;
echo($string."\r");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Look at your server logs. You probably have some error messages about your `mysql` functions failing, and if you were to check the results of your `mysql_query()` calls you'd probably find some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

try writing your query as

```
 SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE subject = '".$requiredsubject."'"
```

if it is a varchar field

better will be

```
 SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE subject LIKE '".$requiredsubject."%'"
```